# How to set up Intellij to run javap command on a program?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I use Intellij Idea for development and I want to configure Intellij to optionally  use javap -c feature . Is there any plugin ? How do I do that ?

Comment: There is also the [ASM Bytecode Outline](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5918?pr=idea) plugin that will show the opcodes. It is available via Settings > Plugins > Browse Repositories.

Comment: In Intelij Idea 14.x you can do it by opening Settings->External Tools and clicking add button. Choose any name and description as you whish, in tool settings set:
Program: '$JDKPath$\bin\javap.exe', 
Parameters: '-c $FileClass$',
Working directory: '$OutputPath$'. 
Now when having your class opened in editor click right mouse button and choose 'External tools-> name_that_you_set'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [configure an external tool](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-third-party-tools.html) to run `javap`.