# View javap -c output within IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, bytecode, javap

I'd like to view Java bytecode the way the command `javap -c` outputs it, not like the "View Bytecode Plugin". Is there a way to accomplish this?

Example: This method

```
public void increment() {
    c++;
}
```

Translates to

```
  public void increment();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: dup
       2: getfield      #2                  // Field c:I
       5: iconst_1
       6: iadd
       7: putfield      #2                  // Field c:I
      10: return
```

Using the `javap -c` command, but in the native bytecode viewer in IntelliJ it looks like this:

```
  // access flags 0x1
  public increment()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 14 L0
    ALOAD 0
    DUP
    GETFIELD ethz/ch/pp/assignment3/counters/SequentialCounter.c : I
    ICONST_1
    IADD
    PUTFIELD ethz/ch/pp/assignment3/counters/SequentialCounter.c : I
   L1
    LINENUMBER 15 L1
    RETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lethz/ch/pp/assignment3/counters/SequentialCounter; L0 L2 0
    MAXSTACK = 3
    MAXLOCALS = 1
```

Which is much more complicated and harder to read. I'd like to view the first without having to first compile the entire project and clutter it with `.class` filed and then executing `javap -c` on only one or two classes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try this plugin:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5918-asm-bytecode-outline

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It doesn't appear to show the bytecode the way I want though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up Intellij to run javap command on a program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458525/how-to-set-up-intellij-to-run-javap-command-on-a-program)